# Entity Framework - NVarchar data type update issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

i am having the problem with insert / update nvarchar model data  in Entity Framework ( Asp.net 4.0 - MVC 4 )

In SQL Server 2008, i have "PhoneNo" [nvarchar(**60**)] column in **UserInfo** table.

Via Entity framework i can able to update from 1 to 30 characters only (which means 50% in that datatype. if length is 100, i can able to save from 1 to 50). Suppose if i give more than 30 chars then throws exception.

{"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Note: Using sql server query i can able to save upto 60 chars. but entity framework i can't.

Please provide me the solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that it's nvarchar in the SQL server? Sounds like it's a varchar... That error's coming from the SQL Server, because the field's too small to accommodate all of the data that you're trying to stuff in it.

Comment: In sql server i can able to save from 1 to 60 chars for nvarchar(60) datatype, but in entity framework i'm getting the error.

Comment: Check the mapping of the EF to table. If EF thinks the field is not unicode, it may trim the string.